# Regex - Match words that contain 2 or more 2 letter sequences of vowels

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to know how to match words (using javascript version of regex) that contain 2 or more 2 letter sequences of vowels (e.g. vis**io**npr**oo**f, st**ea**m**ie**r, pr**ee**q**ui**p).

I'm learning regex at the moments and this is what I have so far (which only matches words containing 2 letter sequence of vowels) and also where I'm stuck at:

[image]

Comment: Just use [`/\b(?:\w*?[aeiou]{2}){2}\w*\b/g`](https://regex101.com/r/CN1ES1/2).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use http://regex101.com whenever I want to test out different regular expressions.  Here is one I came up with that I believe does what you're looking for.

```js
var text = "visionproof vision proof threevowelswouldworktoo queued",
    regex = /\w*[aeiou]{2}\w*[aeiou]{2}\w*/ig;

console.log(text.match(regex));
```

\w matches word characters. So, this matches 0 or more word characters followed by 2 vowels, followed by 0 or more word characters, followed by 2 vowels, followed by 0 or more word characters.  My example is [here](https://regex101.com/r/knUUJQ/3).

Comment: This is incorrect .... it matches much more than a word. https://regex101.com/r/knUUJQ/4

Comment: Thank you for the help I think this should suffice even if some words with digits in them (highly unlikely) may match. And a very thorough explanation with links as well, cheers :).

Comment: if you want to exclude digits, you can replace every occurrence of \w with [a-z].  that change to the regex from @vks makes it only match the word out of that mess.  If you wouldn't want it to find that word at all, put \b at the beginning and end.

Answer (score 1):

1. You will need to group the entire word
2. You probably want to make sure not to catch the vowels group.
3. You want minimum of 2 letters, so you want `{2,}`
4. You will need the `(?:[aeiou]{2,})` part - twice, because you want to catche this more than one time

```
/(\w*(?:[aeiou]{2,})\w*(?:[aeiou]{2,})\w*)/g
```

```js
re = /(\w*(?:[aeiou]{2,})\w*(?:[aeiou]{2,})\w*)/g
str = 'words that contains 2 or more letters sequesnces and some triiiiple visionproof, steamier, preequip'
console.log(str.match(re))
```

Here is a link to regex101:
https://regex101.com/r/OtsdRA/2

> If you want the word `sssiiiisss` not to match (because you don't have two separate blocks of vowels) you should use `\w+` between the two vowels blocks: `/(\w*(?:[aeiou]{2})\w+(?:[aeiou]{2})\w*)/g`

Comment: Your parens are redundant because if you remove all instances of `(?:`, `(`, and `)` from your regex, it still produces the same output: `re = /\w*[aeiou]{2,}\w*[aeiou]{2,}\w*/g`

Comment: Hi thank you for the help and the extra tip or words like sssiiiisss :).

Answer (score 1):

```
\b\w*[aeiou]{2}\w*[aeiou]{2}\w*\b
```

Try this.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/Ph7a0P/3

Answer (score 0):

Below regex can be used for getting 2 or more sequences of 2 consecutive vowels

```
(\w*[aeiou]{2}\w*){2,}
```

{2} for 2 consecutive vowels 
and {2,} for 2 or more sequences