# matching words that contain 2 or more 2-letter sequences of vowels

Tags: python, regex, linux, shell

First of all, I wasn't sure whether I should start a new question because it has already been answered: [Regex - Match words that contain 2 or more 2 letter sequences of vowels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41453008/regex-match-words-that-contain-2-or-more-2-letter-sequences-of-vowels)

(that was a year ago)

HOWEVER, I believe it has been misinterpreted..

**Write a regex that matches words that contain 2 or more 2-letter sequences of vowels** (e.g. vis**io**npr**oo**f, st**ea**m**ie**r, pr**ee**q**ui**p)

and the given answers were quite consistent:

```
(\w*(?:[aeiou]{2})\w*(?:[aeiou]{2})\w*)
```

However, the question asks for **2-letter sequences** and yet, this regex matches (made-up) words like : plooomdooom and leeezaaar, where the vowel sequences have more than 2 vowels

Any ideas how to fix this? I thought that {2} wouldn't allow for the vowels to be repeated more than two times

Comment: So you're asking for a maximum of 2 vowels in sequence? Or are you asking for a maximum of 2 of the same vowel in sequence such that `ooee` is valid but `ooo` is not?

Comment: No, I'm asking for words that have more than two 2-vowel sets.

For example, visionproof would be a good match because it has IO and OO.

But the regex I gave matches words with 3-vowel sets as well - and this is wrong

Comment: That's not wrong. `Beautiful` has 3 consecutive vowels. `Cooeed` has 4 consecutive vowels...

Comment: "Write a regex that matches words that contain 2 or more 2-letter sequences of vowels".

Beautiful doesn't meet this requirement because it has only one 3-letter sequence of vowels. What I'm trying to say is that the sequence of vowels cant be bigger than 2.

Comment: replace `\w` with `[pytrwqsdfghjklmnbvcxz]`, you don't want `[aeiou]` there

Comment: Good point. But now it doesn't match the entire words like visionproof. And it still matches words like: poomzoooom where there is a 4-letter vowel sequence

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this regex:

`\b(?:\w*?(?<![aeiou])[aeiou]{2}(?![aeiou])){2}\w*?\b`

[Click for Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MI99c0/1)

**Explanation:**

- `\b` - a word-boundary
- `(?:\w*?(?<![aeiou])[aeiou]{2}(?![aeiou])){2}`

  - `\w*?` - matches 0+ occurrences of a word-character `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`
  - `(?<![aeiou])[aeiou]{2}(?![aeiou])` - matches 2 consecutive vowels. This match should neither be followed nor preceded by another vowel
  - `{2}` - This will match the above 2 sub-sequences 2 times in the test string
- `\w*?` - Once all the above conditions are satisfied for a test string, we now have 2 occurrences of 2 letter vowels. Now we can match everything until the end of the word. Hence, matching 0+ occurrences of a word-character
- `\b` - a word-boundary

Answer (score 0):

### Code

```
(?<![aeiou])[aeiou]{2}(?![aeiou])
```

#### Usage

[See code in use here](https://ideone.com/Ls8ory)

```
import re

words = [
    "Cooeed",
    "Beautician",
    "Coood",
    "Sit",
    "Beautiful",
    "Steam",
    "Visionproof",
    "Visionproofed",
    "Steamier",
    "Preequip"
]

r = re.compile(r"(?<![aeiou])[aeiou]{2}(?![aeiou])", re.I)

print [w for w in words if len(r.findall(w)) >= 2]
```

---

### Explanation

#### Regex

- `(?<![aeiou])` Negative lookbehind ensuring what precedes is not a character in `aeiou`
- `[aeiou]{2}` Match `aeiou` exactly twice
- `(?![aeiou])` Negative lookahead ensuring what follows doesn't match a character in `aeiou`

#### Generator Expression

- `print [w for w in words if len(r.findall(w)) >= 2]`

  - Prints a list of words from `words` where the regex `(?<![aeiou])[aeiou]{2}(?![aeiou])` matches two or more times